# Is histogram "function" linear?

Tags: statistics, image-processing

I was ask to prove/disprove if for two given images $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ the histogram of  $f_1(x,y)-f_2(x,y)$ and $h_1-h_2$ are equal, where $h_i$ is the histogram of image i.

Intuitively it seems to be correct, as if we look at the images as matrices, the histogram is a function that take the matrix values and count the number of repetitions ("losing" the indices of each value)

But is there a proper mathematically proof?

Answer (score 4):

Consider one-dimensional images
$$f_1=[0,0,0,1]$$
$$f_2=[0,1,0,0]$$
Then we can say that
$$h_1=\begin{bmatrix}(-1,0)\\(0,3)\\(1,1)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$h_2=\begin{bmatrix}(-1,0)\\(0,3)\\(1,1)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$h_1-h_2=\begin{bmatrix}(-1,0)\\(0,0)\\(1,0)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$f_1-f_2=[0,-1,0,1]$$
$$h_{1-2}=\begin{bmatrix}(-1,1)\\(0,2)\\(1,1)\end{bmatrix}$$

In general, if two images are different from each other but have the same histogram, then the histogram of the difference of the images will *not* be equal to the difference of the histograms.

Have I misunderstood something? I don't know if there's even a rigorous idea of "histogram subtraction".

Answer (score 1):

No, the difference of histograms of images is not equal to the histogram of difference of images.

Consider the following counter example:

- $f_1$ image of dimensions $1 \times 1$ with $f_1(0,0) = 0$,
- $f_2$ image of dimensions $1 \times 1$ with $f_2(0,0) = 1$.

Define $f_d(0,0) = f_1(0,0) - f_2(0,0) = 0 - 1 = -1$. Now take the histograms:

- $h[f_1](x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for } x = 1,\\
  1 & \text{for } x = 0,\\
  0 & \text{for } x = -1,
  \end{cases}$
- $h[f_2](x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{for } x = 1,\\
  0 & \text{for } x = 0,\\
  0 & \text{for } x = -1,
  \end{cases}$
- $h[f_1 - f_2](x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for } x = 1,\\
  0 & \text{for } x = 0,\\
  1 & \text{for } x = -1.
  \end{cases}$

The histogram difference results to be

- $(h[f_1] - h[f_2])(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{for } x = 1,\\
  1 & \text{for } x = 0,\\
  0 & \text{for } x = -1.
  \end{cases}$

Hence we deduce that the histogram operator is not linear:
$$ h[f_1 - f_2] \neq h[f_1] - h[f_2].$$